# more efficient version of an id calculator in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

the following function takes two numbers that are linked with a "user" and calculates an id number based on that. i have been trying to make this as clean as possible, and would like some advice on how to make this more efficient.

```
function getidnumber(num, ts) {
            num = num.substr(4, 4);
            ts = ((ts == undefined) ? "3452" : (ts));
            var _local5 = "";
            var _local1 = 0;
            while (_local1 < num.length) {
                var _local4 = Number(num.substr(_local1, 1));
                var _local3 = Number(ts.substr(_local1, 1));
                var _local2 = String(_local4 + _local3);
                _local5 = _local5 + _local2.substr(_local2.length - 1);
                _local1++;
            }
            return("@user" + _local5);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good fit for StackOverflow. If the code works and you're looking for advice on how to improve it try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. But here are a few things I see that can be improved, 1. `ts = ts || '3452'`, 2. `_local5 += _local2.substr(...)`, 3. `return "@user" + _local5`

Comment: thank you, i have been unsuccessful with codereview in the past but i will give it a go

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a zip?

```
function zip() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var shortest = args.length==0 ? [] : args.reduce(function(a,b){
        return a.length<b.length ? a : b
    });
    return shortest.map(function(_,i){
        return args.map(function(array){return array[i]})
    });
}
```